# Use the data send by activity 1 in activity 2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have a Activity1 which sends data to Activity2 using *putExtra* as shown below:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                String itemspi = spinnerFood.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
                i.putExtra("data",itemspi);
                startActivity(i);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity2_layout);
           }
```

I receive this data in Activity2 as below:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String spidata = i.getExtras().getString("data");
```

In Activity2 I am doing *AsyncTask* to push the data (which i received from Activity1) and ID(which is generated locally in Activity2) in a MySql database as below:

new AsyncTask() {

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tagID", ID1));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", spidata));
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_att,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student Present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

When I push the data(ID and the data received from Activy1), the data is successfully inserted into the database(checked using PgAdmin) but the application crashes with the following error:[image]

**Note:** TagViewer(3rd line of error) is my *Activity2*

Down below you can see a error in onCreate:

> [image]

which is referring to this line in the code:

```
spidata = i.getExtras().getString("data");
```

So my guess is when I finish pushing data into the database i say:

```
if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
                        startActivity(i1);
}
```

Which takes the control back to the onCreate method and try to get the intent data but fails and so the application crashes (I might be wrong in this guess).

I need to save the intent data(sent from Activity1) so that the user can push the data(sent from Activity1) and a new ID(generated locally in Activity2) into the database in further iterations.

Please help me guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse the data by starting Activity2 again,you need to add data again to the intent inside AsyncTask()

```
    Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
    i1.putExtra("data",spidata);
    startActivity(i1);
```

Comment: No. I want to save the intent data in Activity2 till the user is on that page.

Comment: see the updated answer,on AsyncTask function you starting Activity2 without any intent data.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It was such a simple thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity2_layout);` after startActivity and put inside `onCreate` of Activity 2.

And get data from intent like this :

**Activity 2**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2_layout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String spidata = i.getExtras().getString("data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the crash but i need that intent data send from Activity1 for the next iteration also. Somehow need to save the intent data for all the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity2_layout);` from Activity1, and then receive the data using this code in Activity2

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        extras = i.getExtras();
        String spidata = extras.getString("data");
```

Comment: Thanks I did that but I need to save the intent data send from Activity1 for pushing it into the database for the second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Going Activity1 to Activity2

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Sending data to mysql

Activity1

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
.....

btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            registerUser();
        }
    });

protected void registerUser() {
String name = Ename.getEditText().getText().toString();
register(name);
}

private void register(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    class ABC extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        ServiceHandler ruc = new ServiceHandler(); 

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Successfully registered")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, name);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }                
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
            data.put("name",params[0]);

            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest("Your url",data);

            return  result;
        }
    }

    ABC ru = new ABC();
    ru.execute(name);
}
```

ServiceHandler

```
public class ServiceHandler {

public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        }
        else {
            response="Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
} 
}
```

Activity2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra(Activity1.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(name);
```